# Q: On Minkowski's inequality

Tags: inequality

It is well known that by applying the function $f(x)=x^p$, $0<p<1$, the inequality $$2^{1-p}(a+b)^p \ge a^p+b^p$$ holds

My question is I want an equivalent form for the reverse inequality but under the assumption $0<p<1$

Comment: You mean $p > 1$ ? because you already had $0 < p < 1$.

Comment: No, I know the inequality will reversed automatically when $p>1$ but i need under the same assumptions we have $\le$. So far as the exists form no way, but let us say is it possible to have in the right hand side $A a^p + B b^p$ , $A,B$ constants (I search for sharp inequality) in any form but we keep $a^p+b^p$